# Rails 4 - Carrierwave image not uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms, nested-attributes

**UPDATE**: Thanks everyone for the help in trying to figure this out. I decided to give up trying to learn and added another image attribute to the profile model. This will have to do for now.

Im trying to make an app in rails 4.

I have a user model, which has an avatar attribute on it.

I also have a profile model.

User :has one profile
Profile :belongs to User

The reason I split them is because profile contains all the variables and user contains all the fixed attributes that cannot be changed without admin permission.

The exception is that my user model has an avatar (image) attribute which I want to allow users to change.

I have user carrierwave in other parts of my code and it works. However, something is wrong in this use case.

I have an avatar uploader with:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
  end

  version :profile do
    process :resize_to_fill => [345,245]
  end

  version :wide do
    process :resize_to_fill => [951,245]
  end

  version :preview do
    process :resize_to_fill => [90,90]
  end

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [35,35]
  end


  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

In my user model i have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

In my user controller - I whitelist the :avatar in strong params.

In my profile controller strong params I've tried adding:

```
params.require(:profile).permit(:title, :overview, user_attributes: [:avatar])
```

And I have also tried allowing user attributes in my profile model (as follows):

```
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

I have a partial form in my views users folder.

```
<%= simple_fields_for :user,  html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :avatar, as: :file, :label => "Add a profile image (head shot)" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That partial is included in my profiles form.

I then want to display the user avatar in my profile show view as:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style= "background-image: url(<%= image_url @profile.user.avatar.url if @profile.user.avatar? %>);">&nbsp;</div>
```

However, it just renders a blank.

I tried:

);">

but it still just renders blank.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

**When i try to test in the rails console by checking the user.avatar, I get this:**

u.avatar
 => #, last_sign_in_ip: #, confirmation_token: "73abb47df224dbc3a612b46ced66e1aba...", confirmed_at: "2016-04-02 07:13:57", confirmation_sent_at: "2016-04-02 22:59:44", unconfirmed_email: "testiest@gmail.com", failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2016-04-02 07:13:57", updated_at: "2016-04-02 22:59:43", avatar: nil, approved: false>, @mounted_as=:avatar>

**TAKING THE SUGGESTION BELOW**

I change my forms so that profile form now has:

```
  <%= render 'users/profileimgform', f: f %>
```

The users/profileimgform now has:

```
<%= simple_fields_for :user,  html: { multipart: true } do |ff| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">


              <%= ff.input :avatar, as: :file, :label => "Add a profile image (head shot)" %>

              </div>


        <% end %>
```

I'm not sure whether I need to incorporate the 'ff' into the line in my profile form. I tried replacing the last 'f' with 'ff' but got an error asking me whether it should be a single 'f'.

When I try this, the console still shows that the user.avatar is 'nil'.

Comment: so the image is not nil, right? You can try it in the console

Comment: it is nil. i added the rails c output above

Comment: You have `storage :fog` so I guess that your remote image storage (S3 or whatever) is properly configured.
You can try in the console uploading a file:
`profile.user.avatar = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'my_file_path.jpg')))`

Comment: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/lem/cl/3/oldway.jpg

Comment: `my_file_path.jpg` is a path to your file into the rails app

Comment: yep -  i swapped that for the name of an image in my app assets images folder

Comment: Change your `storage :fog` TO `storage :file`, to fix it locally. later you can go with `S3`.

Comment: what does later mean? I want it working now

Comment: fix it in development, once it will work in `storage :file` then easy to use `storage :fog`.

Comment: Also, i wanna see `server log` after submitting that form. Can post it too?

Comment: your `server log` or `console log` its same thing. When running `rails s` thats `server log`. I need that part when you trying to upload the image, like after submitting the form.

Comment: "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8e381124c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/75/70zm4s4j14q74tfqpjvh49s80000gp/T/RackMultipart20160403-7383-1oz2jkj.jpg>, @original_filename="oldway.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"oldway.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"9"}

Comment: User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Unpermitted parameter: id

Comment: did you change your `storage :fog` to `storage :file` ? in `avatar_uploader.rb`

Comment: When I change from fog to file - the console shows this output (with the same error display in the view) "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdb11177728 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/75/70zm4s4j14q74tfqpjvh49s80000gp/T/RackMultipart20160403-7543-1uog4rl.jpg>, @original_filename="oldway.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"oldway.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"9"}

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have error with this code:

```
<%= simple_fields_for :user,  html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :avatar, as: :file, :label => "Add a profile image (head shot)" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Look at html that is generated. I think there should be something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :profile do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :avatar %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried this - I updated my question to show my attempt. My user.avatar is still nil.

Comment: Hi Alex - which bit would you like to see? The profile show page where I want to display the avatar? I can see in the console that avatar is nil, so it hasn't saved to the db

Comment: <%= simple_fields_for :user,  html: { multipart: true } do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.error_notification %>
       
     <div class="form-inputs">

     
     <%= ff.input :avatar, as: :file, :label => "Add a profile image (head shot)" %>
       
     </div>

     
  <% end %>

Comment: Sorry Alex. I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that nested form or complex form should connect model and association with `form_for` and `fields_for` helper, like this:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  Addresses:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= addresses_form.label :kind %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :kind %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

The way to connect between model and associations is

- `form_for @person` builds person form instance `f`
- use person form instance `f` to build association form `f.fields_for :addresses` instance `addresses_form`
- use association form input to upload file `addresses_form.input ...`

Last, I guess `simple_fields_for` as [extra helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#extra-helpers) of simple_form, perhaps it only works for `form_for` helper.

---

Here is a example for given models and controllers:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_one :profile
end
```

app/models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Actually, there's two ways to modify model's nested attributes.

1. Modify the model and the nested attributes at the same form

You should build a complex form with both of your model and associations

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

app/controllers/profile_controller.rb

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:title, user_attributes: [:avatar])
  end
end
```

app/views/profile/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :profile do |f| %>
  Avatar:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :user do |uf| %>
      <li>
        <%= uf.label :avatar %>
        <%= uf.file_field :avatar %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

2. Modify the nested attributes only

You could build a normal form just for that association attribute, but it's tricky and vague when you have to initialize it, so I rather not to provide sample code here than confusing you.

Comment: @user2860931, It's complex when you dealing with nested forms, this article may also help: http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by moving avatar from user to profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. If you're on a mac, try installing imagemagik again. I used homebrew. You just need to run this command:

```
brew install imagemagick
```